# Youtube Iframe API - Videos not loading

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

Edit: Here is the JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/sr4u1b0a

I am trying to figure out how to use the YouTube API. I am a newbie at this, so I'm sorry if there is a simple solution.

I believe I added all the necessary code to make it work, it just won't load the video.

https://codepen.io/brianpensinger/pen/zdxzjj

Head:

```
<script src="https://youtube.com/iframe_api" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var player2;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
      player2 = new YT.Player("video-placeholder2", {
        width: 1920,
        height: 1080,
        videoId: "iM_KMYulI_s",
        playerVars: {
          modestbranding: 1,
          rel: 0
        },
        events: {
          onReady: initialize
        }
      });
    }

    function initialize() {
      setPlaybackQuality(highres);
      loadVideoById(iM_KMYulI_s, parseInt(0), highres);
      setPlaybackRate(2);
    }
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var player;

    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
      player = new YT.Player("video-placeholder", {
        width: 1920,
        height: 1080,
        videoId: "iM_KMYulI_s",
        playerVars: {
          modestbranding: 1,
          rel: 0
        },
        events: {
          onReady: initialize
        }
      });
    }

    function initialize() {
      setPlaybackQuality(highres);
      loadVideoById(iM_KMYulI_s, parseInt(0), highres);
      setPlaybackRate(2);
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Please check again the code you provide here in your question and in codepen.io. I think is not complete. For example, if you call `initialize();` you'll get that `setPlaybackQuality is undefined`. Please [edit] your question

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle with your code?

Comment: Here it is!

https://jsfiddle.net/sr4u1b0a/

Thanks in advance for any help. I am new to this Javascript stuff, so I figure I am missing something!

Answer (score 2):

Update, I changed to loading via this script and it worked!

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
```